# Sabre NameRecord Invalid

Tags: sabre

I am working on PassengerDetailsRQ api of sabre . The problem is I am getting the business error while creating a PNR for 2 adults . The soap request format is given below . It works fine on 1 adults but I don't know what is causing the errors in the two adults sample.

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0" IgnoreOnError="true" HaltOnError="true">
<PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="true" RedisplayReservation="true">
    <EndTransactionRQ>
        <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
        <Source ReceivedFrom="Admin"/>
    </EndTransactionRQ>
</PostProcessing>
<PriceQuoteInfo xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
    <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
    <Link NameNumber="1.2" Record="1"/>
</PriceQuoteInfo>
<SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
    <AddRemarkRQ>
        <RemarkInfo>
            <FOP_Remark Type="CASH"/>
        </RemarkInfo>
    </AddRemarkRQ>
    <SpecialServiceRQ>
        <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1960-10-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                    <GivenName>Katharine</GivenName>
                    <Surname>Larson</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <VendorPrefs>
                    <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                </VendorPrefs>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1941-07-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="1.2">
                    <GivenName>Olive</GivenName>
                    <Surname>Robertson</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <VendorPrefs>
                    <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                </VendorPrefs>
            </SecureFlight>
        </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
    <AgencyInfo>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>Lorem Ipsum</AddressLine>
            <CityName>Kathmandu</CityName>
            <CountryCode>NP</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>00977</PostalCode>
            <StreetNmbr>12</StreetNmbr>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="false"/>
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Address>
        <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/>
    </AgencyInfo>
    <CustomerInfo>
        <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="7704372953" PhoneUseType="H"/>
        </ContactNumbers>
        <Email Address="ci@example.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" Infant="false" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>Katharine</GivenName>
            <Surname>Larson</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.2" Infant="false" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>Olive</GivenName>
            <Surname>Robertson</Surname>
        </PersonName>
    </CustomerInfo>
</TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

The error I am getting is as follows :

```
<TYPE>BusinessLogic</TYPE>
<TIMESTAMP>2018-03-24T08:13:43.622-05:00</TIMESTAMP> 
<SYSTEMSPECIFICRESULTS>
 <MESSAGE>
  <content>.NAME NUMBER 1.2 INVALID</content> 
 <CODE>
  ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</CODE></MESSAGE> 
 </SYSTEMSPECIFICRESULTS>
```

I don't see any error . Enhanced air book request gives the success status but the create pnr gives this error . Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 passengers with different Surnames in the same top level number, ie 1.x.

Replace 1.2 with 2.1

Comment: FYI, even it the surnames were the same, the way the service adds people to the PNR, each one would have to have their own number.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't positive there wasn't a way around that.

Comment: The workaround is not worth the difficulty of that and subsequent calls.